# Why isn't MudTooltip not working as expected (not showing)?

Tags: .net, razor, blazor, tooltip, mudblazor

This is my code:

```
<MudTooltip Text="atomic mass">
        <div style="font-size:1.7rem;">@Element.AtomicMass</div>
</MudTooltip>
```

The service is registered like this:

```
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IMudPopoverService, MudPopoverService>();
```

This is my view (my cursor is not visible in the screenshot, but it's right above the div):
[image]

The tooltip is not showing anywhere.

[image]

Comment: Is it just MudToolTip or all the other components ?

Comment: Just the tooltip. Buttons/TextFields etc are working fine

Comment: I added a new image: the element is being created

Answer (score 0):

Based on the [documentation here](https://mudblazor.com/components/tooltip#html-tooltips) I assume the problem is that you need to wrap the tooltip content into `<TooltipContent></TooltipContent>` and the element where the tooltip should be displayed into `<ChildContent></ChildContent>` like this:

```
<MudTooltip Text="atomic mass">
   <ChildContent>
     Hover here
   </ChildContent>
   <TooltipContent>
        <div style="font-size:1.7rem;">@Element.AtomicMass</div>
   </TooltipContent>
</MudTooltip>
```

[TryMudBlazor](https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet/caQmlbccBWodiRzM)

Comment: Yes, I tried that. Same results.

Comment: Can you make a TryMudBlazr reproducible scenario?